# CSS Image on top of another image inside an anchor tag

Tags: html, css, less

I want to put two images inside an anchor tag where the second image is a player button which should be placed on top of the first image.
The anchor tag exists inside a span and that cannot change. Generally the HTML structure of the page cannot change.
Is it possible to achieve this?

This is what I have tried without success.

```css
span.x {
  display: block;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
}
.x img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  .videoicon {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<span class="x">
      <a id="videolink" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ImTTW94ZicM"
         class="video-class" target="_blank">
        <img    src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ImTTW94ZicM/mqdefault.jpg"  border="2px"    alt="Video">
       <img class="videoicon"     src="http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/plazmabursttwo/images/a/a8/Play_button.p   ng/revision/latest?cb=20121111212438" data-pin-nopin="true">
      </a>  
    </span>
```

**EDIT**
There are many span elements with different sizes like the above that should be placed dynamically inside a div every time the page is rendered. So, I am not able to use hard-coded height/width/top etc values.

Thank you

Comment: so the  height of this span is 40px that is fix right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may help you, if `videoicon` has fixed height and width, you can set its position by `calc(50% - half of videoicon's height)` i.e., `calc(50% - 20px)`

```css
span.x {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  height: 220px;
  width: 220px;
}
.x img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.x .videoicon {
  position: absolute;
  top:calc(50% - 20px);
  left:calc(50% - 20px);
  height:40px;
  width:40px;
}
.small{
  margin-top:20px;
height:100px!important;
width:100px!important;
}
```

```html
<span class="x">
  <a id="videolink" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ImTTW94ZicM" class="video-class" target="_blank">
   <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ImTTW94ZicM/mqdefault.jpg"  border="2px" alt="Video" />
   <img class="videoicon"  src="http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/plazmabursttwo/images/a/a8/Play_button.png/revision/latest?cb=20121111212438" data-pin-nopin="true" />
  </a>  
</span>
<span class="x small">
  <a id="videolink" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ImTTW94ZicM" class="video-class" target="_blank">
   <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ImTTW94ZicM/mqdefault.jpg"  border="2px" alt="Video" />
   <img class="videoicon"  src="http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/plazmabursttwo/images/a/a8/Play_button.png/revision/latest?cb=20121111212438" data-pin-nopin="true" />
  </a>  
</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve that with [positioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position). Make the wrapper span `position: relative` to make the childrens position depending on the wrapper. Now just add `position: absolute;` with `top:0;` (or a value that suits your needs) to the second image:

```css
span.x {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
}
.x img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.videoicon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<span class="x">
  <a id="videolink" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ImTTW94ZicM" class="video-class" target="_blank">
   <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ImTTW94ZicM/mqdefault.jpg"  border="2px" alt="Video" />
   <img class="videoicon"  src="http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/plazmabursttwo/images/a/a8/Play_button.png/revision/latest?cb=20121111212438" data-pin-nopin="true" />
  </a>  
</span>
```

For demonstration purposes, I converted your LESS to CSS in the snippet above. The following code would be your LESS:

```
span.x {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
}

.x img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    .videoicon {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;  
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Iam not sure that by adding relative to span it is going to work because many spans with different sizes are placed dynamically in a div every time the page is rendered. Could you please update your answer by taking into consideration that height and width of span is dynamic. It is decided every time the page is rendered. There are images larger and smaller and every time the size of the player image must be adapted depending on size of the background image. Thank you again for your time.

Answer (score 0):

this is Your code in which i have edit some portions

```html
<html>
    <head>
    <style>
    span.x {
    display:block;  
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
 }
    .x >img
 {
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
}
.videoicon{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 50px;
  z-index: 1000;
  overflow: hidden;
  right: 0;  
}
#img11{
width:100%;
height:100%; 
}
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <span class="x">
      <a id="videolink" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ImTTW94ZicM"
         class="video-class" target="_blank">
        <img id="img11" rc="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ImTTW94ZicM/mqdefault.jpg" border="2px" alt="Video">
       <img class="videoicon" src="http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/plazmabursttwo/images/a/a8/Play_button.png/revision/latest?cb=20121111212438" data-pin-nopin="true">
      </a>  
    </span>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much.Could you please update your answer by taking into consideration that height and width of span is dynamic. It is decided every time the page is rendered. There are images larger and smaller and every time the size of the player image must be adapted depending on size of the background image.

Comment: I have also updated my initial question accordingly.

Comment: if u want to use width,height & top dynamically then use bootstrap classes to make it responsive otherwise use Jquery to give dynamic style or classes